# R - sf - create linestrings from sets of coordinate points with missing values

Tags: r, sf

I have a small sample of my dataset in the object named map3. The data contains id (each id corresponds to the beginning and ending coordinate pair), sequence (the order for each id), x (longitude), and y (latitude) for rivers in Tennessee. Please note that there are not ending coordinate pairs for all rivers.

I am attempting to convert the longitude/latitude coordinate pairs to a linestring, but I am getting the following error message:

`# Error in st_cast.POINT(X[[i]], ...) : cannot create LINESTRING from POINT`

The following is the code that I have used:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

map3 <- data.table::data.table(
          id = c(2000L,2000L,2001L,2001L,2002L,2002L,
                 2003L,2003L,2004L,2004L,2005L,2005L,2006L,2006L,2007L,
                 2007L,2008L,2008L,2009L,2009L,2010L,2010L,2011L,2011L,
                 2012L,2012L,2013L,2013L,2014L,2014L,2015L,2015L),
           x = c(-84.6525,-84.6632,-85.5254,NA,-84.8238,
                 -84.8318,-84.8238,-84.8421,-84.6933,-84.7161,-84.6867,
                 -84.7074,-84.7678,-84.766,-84.4276,-84.4045,-84.9256,
                 -84.9261,-84.94035,-84.9385,-87.8131,-87.58061,-88.194516,
                 -88.1938,-85.90994,-85.94,-89.1342,NA,-86.3603,NA,-84.5558,
                 -84.5342),
           y = c(36.4316,36.4359,36.0572,NA,36.5732,
                 36.5781,36.5732,36.5739,36.5556,36.5629,36.5583,36.5676,
                 36.592,36.603,36.571,36.5866,36.5969,36.6109,34.99001,
                 34.99541,36.4985,36.42194,35.083506,35.0847,35.94529,35.863,
                 35.9651,NA,35.8139,NA,34.9884,34.9992),
    sequence = c(1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,
                 2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,2L,1L,
                 2L,1L,2L,1L,2L)
)


map3 %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), na.fail = FALSE) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize() %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING") %>% 
  st_transform("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

What is the correct way to transform coordinate pairs with missing values to a linestring?

Comment: Bit baffled how the NA for coordinate pairs were generated, but were it mine to do, I'd just replace the NA with the last value (or average of preceding/following values), in preference to omitting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100 % sure, but I'd say you were on the right path, but you simply cannot make line geometries (requiring min. two nodes, afaik) from one single point, just as the error message was telling you.

I just filtered out the POINT geometries from your sf object and it seems like this is enough to make `st_cast("LINESTRING")` work. However, your `st_as_sf()` call requires some `crs = ...` definition, otherwise `st_transform()` has nothing to work with - if you even wanted to reproject your data, because I somehow assume you just wanted to provide an initial definition maybe.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

map3 %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), na.fail = FALSE, crs = "epsg:4326") %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize() %>%
  filter(st_geometry_type(.) == "MULTIPOINT") %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING")
#> Simple feature collection with 13 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -88.19452 ymin: 34.9884 xmax: -84.4045 ymax: 36.6109
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 13 × 2
#>       id                                geometry
#>    <int>                        <LINESTRING [°]>
#>  1  2000    (-84.6525 36.4316, -84.6632 36.4359)
#>  2  2002    (-84.8318 36.5781, -84.8238 36.5732)
#>  3  2003    (-84.8421 36.5739, -84.8238 36.5732)
#>  4  2004    (-84.6933 36.5556, -84.7161 36.5629)
#>  5  2005    (-84.6867 36.5583, -84.7074 36.5676)
#>  6  2006       (-84.766 36.603, -84.7678 36.592)
#>  7  2007     (-84.4045 36.5866, -84.4276 36.571)
#>  8  2008    (-84.9261 36.6109, -84.9256 36.5969)
#>  9  2009 (-84.9385 34.99541, -84.94035 34.99001)
#> 10  2010  (-87.8131 36.4985, -87.58061 36.42194)
#> 11  2011  (-88.1938 35.0847, -88.19452 35.08351)
#> 12  2012     (-85.94 35.863, -85.90994 35.94529)
#> 13  2015    (-84.5558 34.9884, -84.5342 34.9992)
```

**Update:**

Regarding your complete dataset and the resulting error message - `#Error in cpp_s2_unary_union(x, options) : Snap function moved vertex (nan, nan, 0.591250531297915) by 3.14159265358979, which is more than the specified snap radius of 0` - with the approach described above, it seems like there are still some x coordinates missing in your sf object, even after filtering for non-emptry geometries via `filter(st_is_empty(.) == FALSE)`.

To tidy this a little bit, I filtered the dataset once more for non-NA x and y before creating an sf object. Apart from that, piping operations did not change.

Currently, the first `filter()` removes incomplete coordinates and the second `filter()` removes incomplete coordinate pairs (only keeping MULTIPOINTS and discarding POINTS) in order to create LINESTRINGS:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

tn_rivers <- readr::read_csv("tn_rivers.csv")

tn_rivers %>%
  filter(is.na(x) == FALSE, is.na(y) == FALSE) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), na.fail = FALSE, crs = "epsg:4326") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize() %>%
  filter(st_geometry_type(.) == "MULTIPOINT") %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING")
#> Simple feature collection with 3218 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -90.2926 ymin: -89.33311 xmax: 86.84629 ymax: 36.6776
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 3,218 × 2
#>       id                             geometry
#>    <dbl>                     <LINESTRING [°]>
#>  1     1   (-84.7524 36.4897, -84.7512 36.49)
#>  2     2   (-84.7376 36.3631, -84.733 36.363)
#>  3     3 (-84.7129 36.5367, -84.7218 36.5439)
#>  4     4 (-84.6048 36.5784, -84.6298 36.5439)
#>  5     5  (-84.5906 36.434, -84.5967 36.4315)
#>  6     6  (-84.7151 36.4447, -84.741 36.4801)
#>  7     7 (-84.7872 36.5154, -84.7919 36.5225)
#>  8     8  (-84.6833 36.568, -84.6719 36.5608)
#>  9     9 (-84.7331 36.5852, -84.7173 36.5849)
#> 10    10 (-84.6578 36.4266, -84.6465 36.4333)
#> # … with 3,208 more rows
```

However, I'd try to tidy this data to remove (or correct) points located not in the US if I were you (as described in the comment), because they seem obviously wrong.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I attempted your solution on the full data set via the following code: `map2 <- fread("https://www.ecoccs.com/tn_rivers.csv"); map3 <- map2 %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), na.fail = FALSE, crs = "epsg:4326") %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize()`; however, I receive the following error message: `#Error in cpp_s2_unary_union(x, options) : Snap function moved vertex (nan, nan, 0.591250531297915) by 3.14159265358979, which is more than the specified snap radius of 0`.

Comment: Probably because some coordinates are incomplete? See `summary(map2)`. x has 20 missing values, y has 18. Also, there are some points located in the Pacific, in Antarctica, in Asia, and so on. Is this on purpose and correct?

Comment: @iembry: Oh, somehow I might have missed this whole "incomplete coordinates" part yesterday. My bad. However, see the update above with my take on your whole dataset.

Comment: The incorrect data points have been revised in the source document. Therefore, I no longer have issues with the missing values. Thank you for your prompt assistance.